# How to do self hosting a wcf service and access it outside in different system

Tags: c#, wcf

My requirement is I want to access a wcf service outside the server where I have developed that. I need to do selfhosting and we don't have IIS there, so i need to do it tcp hosting. Windows service host creating some problem. I want to access that from a different machine.
please share any link or demo application will be great.

Comment: are you able to host it but you can't connect from other machine or is your problem on how to host it?

Comment: is it possible that self hosting will exists even if i close visual studio???

Answer (score 0):

I have created an helper method which hosts my WCF Service taking the URI as parameter, here is the method:

```
 public ServiceHost CreateService(Uri baseAddress)
        {
            // create the net.tcp binding for the service endpoint
            NetTcpBinding ntcBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            ntcBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding tcpBinding = ntcBinding;

            // create the service host and add the endpoint
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RMS.Gateway.Services.RiskLinkService), baseAddress);

            host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
            host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
            host.Closing += new EventHandler(host_Closing);
            host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);
            host.Faulted += new EventHandler(host_Faulted);
            host.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(host_UnknownMessageReceived);

            // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            // If not, add one
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

            //smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Add MEX endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
              "mex"
            );

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(RAE.Entities.ServiceInterfaces.IRiskLinkService), ntcBinding, string.Empty);

            host.Open();

            return host;
        }
```

then from a test Console application I use this method to start the hosting, it could be done in a similar way inside a windows service, in production we will but for now and for simple debugging we host in the console app :)

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceURL"]);

        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (ServiceHost host = serviceFactory.CreateService(baseAddress))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            System.Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHost.
            host.Close();
        }
```

as you can see NetTcpBinding is created at runtime from code, it works and we can access and use the WCF end points from other machines in the network.

Comment: See i have 2 machine one where i want to put my wcf service and one where i want to call the wcf. so where should i put this code?

Comment: this code is ALL in the WCF server, this does not call it but sets it up to be hosted in a Console application and yes, if you close Visual Studio and such console application is not running anymore, of course your WCF will not be responding to client calls...

Comment: @Bijay But you can close Visual Studio and leave the console application running - you **do not** need to have Visual Studio open in order to run the WCF service. You do not even need Visual Studio installed to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [step by step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) guide of microsoft can help you in hosting the wcf service and consuming the service.